# Excel VBA w/ File Picker-Combine 2 files in New document & Apply Formula for Comparison

Tags: vba, excel

A retiree friend leaving wants to leave a "present" and I'm trying to help.
A file is open and the macro is run, a file picker dialog allows the user to select the first file,columns removed, items are filtered out and deleted, the file picker then allows the user to choose a second file, items are filtered out and deleted,columns removed, the two sheets are combined into one and the new file is saved in a different location.

```
Sub SectionEightReport()
 Dim fd As FileDialog
 Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'speed up macro execution
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With fd
 'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    .InitialFileName = "\\marnv006\Bm\Master Scheduling\DSC 2.3.4 Engineering Job Release Metrics\Blue Deck\"
    If .Show = -1 Then
    'The user pressed the action button.
    'switch of updating to speed your code & stop irritating flickering
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            rc = ShellExecute(0, "open", vrtSelectedItem, vbNullChar, _
            vbNullChar, 1)
            Application.CutCopyMode = True

            DoEvents
```

Not sure how to proceed here...
User will open the first file (latest file) like:

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "\\marnv006\Bm\Master Scheduling\DSC 2.3.4 Engineering Job Release Metrics\Blue Deck\Blue Deck 2016\Section 5\Section 5_11_07_2016.xls"
```

Columns N:V in this document get deleted and the sheet renamed to "Section 5 (Current) Something like:

```
    Columns("N:V").Delete
```

Then all items with values of "1/0/1900" & "N/A" get deleted

User will open the previous file something like:

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "\\marnv006\Bm\Master Scheduling\DSC 2.3.4 Engineering Job Release Metrics\Blue Deck\Blue Deck 2016\Section 5\Section 5_10_24_2016.xls"
```

Columns N:V in this document get deleted and the sheet renamed to "Section 5 (Previous)"

```
    Columns("N:V").Delete
```

The two sheets get combined into one workbook.
New file will be saved in `"\\marnv006\\Bm\Master Scheduling\DSC 2.3.4 Engineering Job Release Metrics\Blue Deck\Blue Deck 2016\Section 8\"`

The file name will be `"Section_8_"` & the date in the format likes this `"11_11_2016"`

Then in Column N6:N of the "Section 5 (Current)" sheet an Index Match is applied.
Something like `"=OFFSET(INDEX('Section 5 (Previous)'!R6C1:R[1994]C1,MATCH('Section 5 (Current)'!RC1,'Section 5 (Previous)'!R6C1:R[1994]C[-13],0)),0,12)"`
also `"=OFFSET(INDEX('Section 5 (Previous)'!$A$6:$A1889,MATCH('Section 5 (Current)'!$A6,'Section 5 (Previous)'!$A$6:A1889,0)),0,12)"`

The header of this column is `"Previous DSC Release Schedule"` and the text is wrapped.
In column O6 the formula `"=N6-M6"` is applied through the last row.
This column header is "Variance (Days) and the text is wrapped.
Column N is formatted as a date; something like:

```
    Columns("N:N").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Column O is formatted as a number; something like:

```
        Columns("O:O").Select
                Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
```

Finally, in column O ""Variance (Days)") all items with "0" are deleted.
File is saved as mentioned above

```
End Sub
```

[image: Example of Final Result]

Comment: So... what is the question?

Comment: The question(s) are in line with the code

Comment: I don't see any questions, just a specification.  *Which exact part* are you having a problem with?

Comment: How can I use a file picker to choose two files and have them combined into one file given the specifications; particularly start from where I saw "I'm not sure how to proceed..."